# What is the difference between these Windows WSL: Ubuntu vs Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS in the Windows app store?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, windows-store-app, ubuntu-22.04

Windows app store offers two Ubuntu WSL apps (as of 11/20/2023):

- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

[image: Screenshot: Windows Store' WSL Ubuntu Apps]

**What's the difference between them?**

Comment: LTS means Long Term Support

Comment: There are point releases for all of the supported versions of Ubuntu that *will not* nag you about upgrading. The plain release will choose the newest (possibly only LTS) version and *will* nag you to `do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to look at the details of each entry to understand.

- "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS" has the Release Date of 25/10/2021
- "Ubuntu" has the Release Date of 14/03/2022

The logic behind these releases is explained in the article
[A Guide to Upgrading your Ubuntu App’s Release](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/upgrading-ubuntu/).

The idea is that "Ubuntu" is the latest version that's available
on the Store, while "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS" is just exactly version
22.04.2 LTS.
The Store also contains even older releases, for people who need
a specific release number.

Answer (score -1):

This app installs the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS release on Windows

[image: wsl]

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  `Ubuntu` would install the current latest recommended LTS release while `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS` would install that specific LTS release.

Comment: [Ubuntu on Windows](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/ubuntu-on-windows/9NBLGGH4MSV6?hl=en-US&gl=US) != [Ubuntu](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/ubuntu/9PDXGNCFSCZV?hl=en-us&gl=US).  You are looking at the wrong thing.  The way I can tell, that the description in your link, includes 2 year old install instructions.